# Check if element exists on page and continue if not using python

Tags: python, jquery, selenium

Trying to resolve an issue where I need to check if an element is on a page if it exists then perform a piece of code if not then continue with script. The issue I have is that if the element does not appear then script fails with 'Failed to find element'

What I currently have is:

```
form_error = s.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class,'screen-new-error')]")
form_error = form_error.get_attribute('textContent')
form_error = form_error[6:].strip()
             
if form_error == "There was a problem with the Form":
   result = "FAIL"
else:
  result = "PASS"
```

Comment: What does `get_attribute` do? Maybe something needs to be changed there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a few options:

1.

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException        
def check_exists_by_xpath(xpath):
    try:
        webdriver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        return False
    return True
```

2. call `find_element` inside a `try/catch`